# What advantages do smaller countries have over bigger ones for achieving effectiveness?

Tags: government

https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/wb_government_effectiveness/

> Definition: The index of Government Effectiveness captures perceptions
> of the quality of public services, the quality of the civil service
> and the degree of its independence from political pressures, the
> quality of policy formulation and implementation, and the credibility
> of the government's commitment to such policies.

What advantages do smaller countries have over bigger ones for achieving effectiveness? Looking at the chart, it seems that the most effective governments tend to be smaller, although some smaller countries aren't effective at all, but this suggests that it might give some advantages over bigger ones, why exactly is this the case?

Comment: This seems rather obvious to me... Distance is a thing and so a more compact territory and population is inherently easier to govern and provide efficient services to, all else being equal?

Comment: One needs to be careful in comparing units of different sizes. Smaller sizes have typically larger variances. It's not a surprise they appear on top and on the bottom as you observe. You rather should look at means. Do small countries on average fare better than bigger ones should be the question. And small countries may also have disadvantages (less scaling benefits for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are two effects at work here. The first one is a purely statistical artifact. The variance of a measure like that is much bigger among small countries then among big ones. You can think of a big country as an average of a bunch of small ones, so their scores will in general be closer to the global average. This is a very general effect that applies in a lot of settings, if you measure some quantity among entities of very different sizes, the most extreme scores will be among the small entities. This effect is generally much stronger than small differences between the average of all small entities versus the average of all big entities.

The second effect actually relates to government efficiency and I would call it the number of layers. The lowest levels of government handle a roughly similar amount of people in different countries and each level above can handle a roughly similar amount of smaller units. So the bigger countries need more levels in total and the highest levels are further removed from the local day-to-day governing. This makes the larger countries less efficient because the top level needs to impose rules that work for a large number of very different localities whereas a group of small countries can have very different rules among them.

Comment: Large countries might also be federated (India, USA, Brazil, Russia, Mexico, ...). That way, the top level does not need to impose as many rules for very different localities. On the flip-side, you get very different rules and duplicate structures in different parts of the country which are also a source of inefficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer covered the main points but I'll add one about geopolitics.

Small countries are often not really independent. Instead, they become dominated by a large country, which influences the government of the country in various ways.

Populations can develop pluralism, but an expansionist government has no reason to be arguing with itself. It will probably just pick one policy and stick to it. Or rather make the small country stick to it.

This results in unity and coherence, which can be efficient and stable.

Also, if the patron country decides that the small one is strategically important, they can easily shower them with money or resources. What's 1% of the budget to one country, can double the GDP of another. You can easily say that this is not really *efficiency*, but it is an advantage.

Comment: If you look at the countries in the top 10 of the list, Singapore plus a bunch of small European countries, this argument doesn't really apply. Andorra is the only one where you could argue that it is dominated by larger countries.